# Running the .exe file from Visual Studio folder closes the window automatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I created a game with SDL and C++ in Visual Studio. This game was made for my university (computer science).

When I run it from Visual Studio everything runs perfectly. When I go to the folder of the project and run it through the .exe file it pops up and then it closes immediately. My properties in the system are already in Windows application, multithreaded dll.

I don't get it — it should work fine since I can run it through the solution explorer without any warnings/errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your program rely on any DLL files (you're using SDL, so it should). Where are they located, relative to your `.exe` ?

Comment: @grgarside You're making super high quality edits, greatly appreciated!

Comment: the dll files are on the same folder as the.exe . In case they were not, i would have error from the solution explorer that the dll files were missing. other than that i have many .png images and font on the folder's game but they are not in the same directory as the .exe file. i will check it now maybe this is the problem, w8 a sec.

Comment: hahahaahha i am laughing my ass out of your comment it was funny :) well i did it and it worked , but why did this happen? i mean the images should be on the same folder? if thats the case why the solution explorer did run the app perfectly? it works now..

Answer (score 1):

When you start your exe from the Explorer, the current directory changes. Your program most likely cannot find dependencies, either dlls or resources like graphics and sound. A short term solution would be to make sure your files are in the right place. Long-term, you should have better error handling in your program, so you get an error message you can work with.

Comment: Well i did copied all the imaged on the .exe folder and it worked. I have error checking but only in the solution explorer. For example if i have an image whitch is not intilize my app will return 1, if its a sound 2 and so on. Any better way to do it ?

Comment: @KostasRimis obviously your current error reporting is not sufficient or this post would not exist. Error reporting is for *you*, not anyone else, so what would *you* like your program to do when it fails? Personally, I would have liked a messagebox saying "image C:\foo\bar.jpg could not be found". That's crystal clear.

Comment: Another good practice for development is to use a log, which clearly states what the program is loading so you can inspect when it fails